# How do I drop a MongoDB database from the command line?

Tags: mongodb

What's the easiest way to do this from my bash prompt?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366397/delete-everything-in-a-mongodb-database. It's really easy to do it from the mongo shell.

Answer (score 1162, accepted):

Like this:

```
mongo <dbname> --eval "db.dropDatabase()"
```

More info on scripting the shell from the command line here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#scripting

Edit:

In Mongo 6.0 `mongo` was removed and replaced with `mongosh` which has to be installed separately. More info here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongosh

The equivalent in `mongosh` would be:

```
mongosh --eval "use <dbname>" --eval  "db.dropDatabase()"
```

Comment: This was very helpful in my case. Somehow I had a database named "mean-dev" from an older installation, and entering "mean-dev.dropDatabase()" in the mongo shell resulted in "ReferenceError: mean is not defined". But using the solution in this answer did the trick. +1

Comment: If you want to get a human readable result, do it this way:

```mongo <dbname> --eval "printjson(db.dropDatabase())"```

Comment: K. P. MacGregor. you should have been: "use mean-dev" + "db.dropDatabase()"

Comment: Thanks. This is how you can customise host and port:

`mongo <yourDb> --host <yourHost> --port <yourPort> --eval 'db.dropDatabase()'`

Comment: Now, when "mongo" was removed, you can do it like this: `mongosh <dbname> --eval "printjson(db.dropDatabase())"`.

Answer (score 906):

The best way to do it is from the mongodb console:

```
> use mydb; 
> db.dropDatabase();
```

Alternatively, you can stop `mongod` and delete the data files from your data directory, then restart.

Hint: you can also move the data files to a subfolder, and delete them if you're sure you no longer need them.

Comment: I think he means directly from the prompt doesn't he? In that case you either have to generate a .js file with those commands and invoke it from the prompt using "mongo dropdb.js" or something or do as you say and remove the files manually.

Comment: but be aware that you cannot use `use` command in .js file, you have to connect to concrete DB (specify dbname for mongo command)

Comment: Pro Tip: after dropping a database, you might want to exit the mongo shell and delete your `~/.dbshell` file to clear your command history. (There may be a better way of doing that - I'm not sure.)

I do this because, unlike with SQL, the mongo command to drop a database _does not actually reference the name of the database to drop_ - it just drops the database to which the client is currently connected. Clearing your command history will prevent your from accidentally replaying the `dropDatabase` command and unintentionally dropping a second database.

Comment: That's a smart idea, @chrisallenlane. The mongodb shell is quite a dangerous tool at times... :)

Comment: **Warning:** If you drop a database and create a new database with the same name, you must either restart all mongos instances, or use the flushRouterConfig command on all mongos instances before reading or writing to that database. This action ensures that the mongos instances refresh their metadata cache, including the location of the primary shard for the new database. Otherwise, the mongos may miss data on reads and may write data to a wrong shard.

Comment: @Lekr0 In MongoDB version 4.4 and newer the `flushRouterConfig` is not required anymore, see [Improved Routing Table Updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.4/#improved-routing-table-updates)

Comment: Please, anybody, don't be stupid as me and stop all the programs running in the background that can be possibly using Mongo because it can (obviously) create the database you just removed and make it look like the dropDatabase() command doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 130):

I found this easy to remember:

```
mongo //to start the mongodb shell

show dbs //to list existing databases

use <dbname> //the <dbname> is the database you'd like to drop

db //should show <dbname> just to be sure I'm working with the right database

db.dropDatabase() //will delete the database & return { "dropped" : "<dbname>", "ok" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 118):

**You don't need heredocs or eval**, `mongo` itself can act as an interpreter.

```
#!/usr/bin/env mongo
var db = new Mongo().getDB("someDatabase");
db.dropDatabase();
```

Make the file executable and run it.

Comment: Note that the script name must end with `.js`, otherwise it will be interpreted as the db address.

Comment: @Vegard That's not correct. You're running `mongo filename` which is unnecessary - the file already has an interpreter in the top line. Just make the file executable and run it `./filename`

Comment: @mikemaccana I know that, but doing `./filename` will actually run `/usr/bin/env mongo filename`, right? And so if `filename` doesn't end in `.py`, mongo will not recognise the argument as a script to run.

Comment: "Doing ./filename will actually run /usr/bin/env mongo filename, right?" No. Check the output of `ps`.

Comment: @mikemaccana The output of `ps` only shows you what's running at the time you invoke `ps`, not the chain of `exec` calls that lead to that point nor the work the kernel has done to load and execute the file. If you want to know what's really going on, you should use write a wrapper around `/usr/bin/env`, set that as the executable in the shebang line, and then kick the whole thing off with `strace`.

Comment: @Vegard that is correct (except that it needs to be `.js` and not `.py`) and it will fail if your filename doesn't end in `.js`

Comment: @kbolino ack re strace or systemtap being better than a ps point-in-time, but Vegard's statement that this will attempt to run `/usr/bin/env mongo filename` and therefore the file must end in `.py` is provably incorrect.

Comment: @mikemaccana only because it should be `.js` -- the kernel will execute the equivalent of `/usr/bin/env mongo filename` which will eventually lead to a call to `mongo filename` for some `mongo` on the path, which means the filename will be treated as the database name, not the script to execute, unless it ends in `.js`, per the docs (and the docs are accurate on this point, at least for 3.x)

Comment: @mikemaccana Regardless of what actually gets executed, the need for the file name to end in `.js` is testable (again, at least on 3.x). Create a script called `foo`, copy and paste the exact content of your answer, `chmod +x foo`, then run `./foo`. It will fail and the failure message will include `connecting to: mongodb://./foo`. Change the file name to `foo.js` and it works.

Comment: @kbolino The interpreter is handled by Unix/Linux and not Mongo, and the answer has been tested. Unless Mongo itself is now a python interpreter rather than a JS one in Mongo 3, the result shouldn't change.

Comment: @mikemaccana It has nothing to do with Python (that was just a typo many comments ago). The filename has to end in `.js` or Mongo won't interpret it *at all* because it treats the argument as the name of the database to use, not the script to execute.

Comment: @kbolino Repeating: interpreters are handled by Unix/Linux and not Mongo. Also repeating: try it.

Comment: @mikemaccana A year ago, I had tried it with 3.0.5. I just tried it again with 3.4.6. Nothing has changed in a year. The file name must end with `.js`. I have posted the exact steps to demonstrate the problem. I respectfully request that *you* try what I've done and see for yourself.

Comment: for absolute clarity, here is a sequence of shell commands that will demonstrate the problem: https://pastebin.com/Tpt474te

Comment: [mongo/shell/shell_options.cpp:400](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/73a74e4ba33af61b2f102ddf11e674ee30dc2768/src/mongo/shell/shell_options.cpp#L400) shows the argument parsing logic and why `.js` is required; but, it also shows that another way to solve this problem is to make the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env mongo --nodb` -- then you can use whatever file extension you like (or none at all)

Answer (score 31):

Start MongoDB

Command for Database drop is :

**1.** first select the database which you want to delete

```
use < database name >
```

**2.** Then use this..

```
db.dropDatabase()
```

Answer (score 29):

You could also use a "heredoc":

```
mongo localhost/db <<EOF
db.dropDatabase()
EOF
```

Results in output like:

```
mongo localhost/db <<EOF
db.dropDatabase()
EOF
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
connecting to: localhost/db
{ "dropped" : "db", "ok" : 1 }    
bye
```

I like to use heredocs for things like this, in case you want more complex sequence of commands.

Answer (score 23):

Here are some use full delete operations for mongodb using mongo shell

To **delete particular document** in collections: `db.mycollection.remove( {name:"stack"} )`

To **delete all documents** in collections:  `db.mycollection.remove()`

To **delete collection** :  `db.mycollection.drop()`

to **delete database** :
first go to that database by `use mydb` command and then

```
db.dropDatabase()
```

directly from command prompt or blash : `mongo mydb --eval "db.dropDatabase()`

Answer (score 19):

Other way:

```
echo "db.dropDatabase()" | mongo <database name>
```

Answer (score 15):

Execute in a terminal:

```
mongo // To go to shell

show databases // To show all existing databases.

use <DATA_BASE> // To switch to the wanted database.

db.dropDatabase() // To remove the current database.
```

Comment: Same answer as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857276/how-do-i-drop-a-mongodb-database-from-the-command-line/18997305#18997305), which was given a month earlier.

Answer (score 11):

Open another terminal window and execute the following commands,

```
mongodb
use mydb
db.dropDatabase()
```

Output of that operation shall look like the following

```
MAC:FOLDER USER$ mongodb
> show databases
local      0.78125GB
mydb       0.23012GB
test       0.23012GB
> use mydb
switched to db mydb
>db.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "mydb", "ok" : 1 }
>
```

Please note that `mydb` is still in use, hence inserting any input at that time will initialize the database again.

Answer (score 5):

Using Javascript, you can easily create a *drop_bad.js* script to drop your database:

create *drop_bad.js*:

```
use bad;
db.dropDatabase();
```

Than run 1 command in terminal to exectue the script using mongo shell:

```
mongo < drop_bad.js
```

Answer (score 4):

Open a terminal and type:

```
mongo
```

The below command should show the listed databases:

```
show dbs 

/* the <dbname> is the database you'd like to drop */
use <dbname> 

/* the below command will delete the database */
db.dropDatabase()
```

The below should be the output in the terminal:

```
{
  "dropped": "<dbname>",
  "ok": 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

one liner remote remove all collections from mongo database

note must use --host, (-h is help for mongo command), and -d is not an option, select the db and command after password.

```
mongo --host <mongo_host>:<mongo_port> -u <db_user> -p <db_pass> <your_db> --eval "db.dropDatabase()"
```

Answer (score 3):

Surprised that we haven't seen this variation come up.  This minimizes extra args on the command line and explicitly shows the DB being switched to `FOO` and then dropped:

```
$ mongo --host "mongodb://machine:port" --eval 'db.getSiblingDB("FOO").dropDatabase();'
```

Answer (score 2):

In you command prompt, First connect to mongodb using following command:

```
mongo -h [host-name]:[port:number] -d [dbname] -u [username] -p [password]
```

you will be accessing db with `<dbname>`.

Run the following command to drop the whole database:

```
db.dropDatabase()
```

Comment: -h is help, -d is not an option
more like

`
mongo --host [host-name]:[port:number] -u [username] -p [password] [dbname] --eval "db.dropDatabase()"
`

Answer (score 2):

Eventhough there are several methods, The best way (most efficient and easiest) is using `db.dropDatabase()`

Answer (score 0):

LogIn into your mongoDB command line:
And type the below commands.
**use "YOUR_DATABASE_NAME";**
**db.dropDatabase();**

Answer (score 0):

In order to be really sure that you drop the correct database use

```
mongo <connection properties> --eval "db.getSiblingDB('dbname').dropDatabase()"
```

See [Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470) to understand the concerns.

Answer (score -1):

use following command from mongo shell to drop db

```js
use <database name>; 
db.dropDatabase();
```

Comment: how does this command specify which database to drop? With a database called "auth-users" I tried `> use auth-users ; db.dropDatabase()` and `> use auth-users; db.dropDatabase()` and both returned `[thread1] Error: [auth-users ; db.dropD
atabase()] is not a valid database name :`

Answer (score -1):

**db** will show the current Database name
type: **db.dropDatabase();**

1- select the database to drop by using '***use***' keyword.

2- then type ***db.dropDatabase();***

Answer (score -1):

Drop a MongoDB database using python:

```
import argparse

import pymongo


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    Drop a Database.
    """

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--host", default='mongodb://localhost:27017',
                        help="mongodb URI [default: %(default)s]")
    parser.add_argument("--database", default=None,
                        help="database name: %(default)s]")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    client = pymongo.MongoClient(host=args.host)

    if args.database in client.list_database_names():
        client.drop_database(args.database)
        print(f"Dropped: '{args.database}'")
    else:
        print(f"Database '{args.database}' does not exist")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can first **switch to your database** which you want to delete. Then you can delete the same by using the command **dropDatabase()**.

Code :

`>use dbName`

`>db.dropdataBase()`

The result will be :

```
{ "dropped" : "dbName", "ok" : 1 }
```

If you want to delete a **specific collection in a database**, then switch to the database and enter the following command.

Code:

`>use dbName`

`db.collection.drop()`

The result will be :

```
true
```

> If you want a better understanding of MongoDB shell commands it's
> better to follow the documentation always.
>
> Link to the documentation :
> https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/#std-label-js-administrative-methods