# Numeric Collection Name Remove

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

How can you drop a numeric collection from MongoDB?

```
PRIMARY> db.123456789011.remove({});
Tue Mar 20 08:42:51 SyntaxError: missing ; before statement (shell):1

PRIMARY> db.123456789011.drop({});
Tue Mar 20 08:43:13 SyntaxError: missing ; before statement (shell):1
```

Was created through a PHP script.. now I can't figure out how to remove this..

Thoughts?

Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should work:

```
   db["123456789011"].drop()
```

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same issue with a collection generated by a java class

```
db["1234"].drop()
Wed Jul  9 14:57:39.358 TypeError: Cannot call method 'drop' of undefined
```

and at the end used the following command to remove it.

```
db.getCollection('1234').drop()
```