# how to mock database Nodejs and Express js Unit Testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, chai

i am using Express js and Mysql for my application, now i want to start unit testing. I have written this code:

```
var request = require('supertest');
var server = require('./app');
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

var server = require('./app');

var should = chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('loading express', function () {

  it('responds to /', function testSlash(done) {
    request(server)
      .get('/')
      .expect(200, done);
  });

  it('404 everything else', function testPath(done) {
    request(server)
      .get('/foo/bar')
      .expect(404, done);
  });

  it('responds to /customers/getCustomerData', function testPath(done) {
    request(server)
      .get('/customers/getCustomerData?id=0987654321')
      .end(function(err, res){
        res.should.have.status(200);
        res.body.should.be.a('object');
        res.body.status.should.equal("success");
        res.body.data.customerId.should.equal("0987654321");

        done();
      });
  });

});
```

This code is working properly but it makes connection to database and checking all the test cases which i have written, but this is called integration testing i have to do unit testing using mock database. How can i achieve this mocking of database?

Comment: What do you use to connect to db? Sequelize?

Comment: No i am using Node ORM2

Comment: You have 2 options. One to mock the orm, but better than that use in memory db in tests - sqlite, if your orm supports that.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526160/mocking-database-in-node-js

Comment: Please provide the code under test. So we can know how to mock your DB.