# How can I make unit test on a nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I want to make some unit tests on my nodejs app in order to test the insertion of a user on a database or the read of a user from the database.
I'm using Objection.js such an ORM and I searched through the net how to do these Test, thus I found [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) to mock a database or a model.Concerning this issue I found also this question [Mocking database in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526160/mocking-database-in-node-js).
For example if I have a table `Users` contains 10 users, is there any solutions to get all the rows of such table for example of fetch if a user exists in the table? I don't really understand the concept of mocking and if it is the suitable solution to make such tests?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of libs for unit testing of NodeJS such as Moca, Chai, Jasmine.

here is some tutorial link:

https://www.codementor.io/davidtang/unit-testing-and-tdd-in-node-js-part-1-8t714s877

https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-unit-testing-tutorial/

Comment: But there is no useful link to make a test of database