# Bluemix/CloudFoundry + Meteor - How to Project Reset?

Tags: meteor, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

When developing with Meteor locally, one execute `meteor reset` locally to refresh the database.

Can one run this command on a production level app deployed on Bluemix without digging into the Mongo console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `meteor reset` command actually deletes the local mongo database files in `.meteor/local`. Since the database isn't stored in the application container when running in Cloud Foundry, there isn't an equivalent operation as a one liner.

Seems like your only option is to retrieve the connection credentials from your application `cf env appname` and then stop the application, connect with the mongo command line, and use one of the methods [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366397/delete-everything-in-a-mongodb-database) to clean your data out.